# Databricks missing values not appearing in counts

Tags: r, formatting, databricks, missing-data

All steps carried out in Databricks.

I have loaded my cleaned dataset in Databricks and the variables do not show any of the missingness in the summary or colSums(is.na(df)) commands.  I know they are there from earlier work and viewing them directly.

I have also formatted the relevant variables to numeric and POSIXct, while leaving the remainder as characters, however one of the datetime variables will not format correctly, when in previous work it did.

I am somewhat lost with this and sorry for not including specific examples in this query.

Has anyone else encountered this issue.

Comment: Can you include a reproducible example in your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example